# NSAttributedString loading html with images

Tags: html, ios7, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to render html-document with `NSAttributedString` in iOS 7 (as a part of investigation of the alternatives to UIWebView). Here the code:

```
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.chapterPath];

NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData
                                                                  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} 
                                                       documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

self.readerTextView.attributedText = attrString;
self.readerTextView.editable = NO;
```

And images were not displayed. Is it possible to render HTML with images using this approach or did I miss some options or attributes? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Some of the tags that were not displayed:

```
<img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="cover" style="height: 100%"/>
```

Comment: Where are you rendering the HTML?  Why does the HTML need to be within an attributed string when a plain string will hold it?

Comment: I try to render in the UITextView. iOS 7 introduced support of the HTML for NSAttributed string

Comment: Surely that's just HTML text styling, not full HTML 5 support?

Comment: Just simple <img> tag.

Comment: So you expect the `UITextView` to fetch the image data from whereever the `img` tag tells it and display the image?  I think you need to investigate a bit more about what HTML features are supported and what are not (and as I say, I'm pretty sure it will be restricted to text styling).

Comment: Yes. It was rather fuzzily described in documentation: "The HTML import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML import." (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) And because of that I want to clarify is it possible or not.

Comment: But given the support is within the `NSAttributedString` class, it's a reasonable to assume it can only support HTML features that can be expressed within the attributed string, and that excludes image support.  What you want is a web view.

Comment: trojanfoe, you are right. NSAttributedString while loading this html doesn't contain anything related to the image.

Comment: trojanfoe, unfortunately I've made mistake it's possible to render images by this way.

Comment: <img> tag works fine with width and height attributes specified and it doesn't render an image without those size attribute

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to render HTML with images using `NSAttributedString`. Problem is in "src" attribute I think relative link doesn't work. Full links via `file://` or to the Internet resource via `http`/`https` are acceptable.

Article with working example:

http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2013/09/29/easy-markdown-rendering-with-nsattributedstring-on-ios-7/
https://github.com/ericallam/MarkyMark

Answer (score 1):

Including an  tag seems to be OK on iOS 14, but is not OK on Mac Catalyst 14, the NSAttributedString call fails. From the docs for NSAttributedString: "Calling it from the main thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs). The HTML import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML import."